# Understanding Markov Chain source code in R

Tags: r, statistics, probability, markov-chains, markov

The following source code is from a book. Comments are written by me to understand the code better.

```
#==================================================================
# markov(init,mat,n,states) = Simulates n steps of a Markov chain 
#------------------------------------------------------------------
# init = initial distribution 
# mat = transition matrix 
# labels = a character vector of states used as label of data-frame; 
#           default is 1, .... k
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
markov <- function(init,mat,n,labels) 
{ 
    if (missing(labels)) # check if 'labels' argument is missing
    {
        labels <- 1:length(init) # obtain the length of init-vecor, and number them accordingly.
    }

    simlist <- numeric(n+1) # create an empty vector of 0's
    states <- 1:length(init)# ???? use the length of initial distribution to generate states.
    simlist[1] <- sample(states,1,prob=init) # sample function returns a random permutation of a vector.
                        # select one value from the 'states' based on 'init' probabilities.

    for (i in 2:(n+1))
    { 
        simlist[i] <- sample(states, 1, prob = mat[simlist[i-1],]) # simlist is a vector.
                                                    # so, it is selecting all the columns 
                                                    # of a specific row from 'mat'
    }

    labels[simlist]
}
#==================================================================
```

I have a few confusions regarding this source code.

Why is `states <- 1:length(init)` used to generate states? What if states are like  ***S*** *={-1, 0, 1, 2,...}*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names of the states don't really need to have any statistical meaning as long as they are different. So, while simulating transitions between states, it's perfectly fine to choose `states <- 1:length(init)` or any other names for them. Ultimately, though, for practical purposes we often have in mind some labels in mind, such as -1, 0, ..., n, as in your example. You can provide those names as the `labels` parameter and then `labels[simlist]` will rename `1:length(init)` to `labels`, element by element. I.e., if initially we had `c(1, 2, 3)` and you provided `labels` as `c(5, 10, 12)`, then the output will be in terms of the latter vector. For instance,

```
(states <- sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE))
# [1] 1 3 3 2 2 1 2 1 3 3
labels <- c(5, 10, 12)
labels[states]
# [1]  5 12 12 10 10  5 10  5 12 12
```

Comment: *Names of the states don't really have any statistical meaning as long as they are different.* - What if we need to calculate expectation?

Comment: @user366312, yes, you are right, names *can* be meaningful, though I'd add that one should think before doing something like calculating expectations. For example, if there are just two states, 0 and 1, is something like 0.65 as the expected value a meaningful figure? Regardless of this good point, the rest of my post answers the technical part of your question. In particular, even if those names matter for some *subsequent* analysis, they do not matter for the simulation part, which makes it ok to use `1:length(init)`.

Comment: Why is `labels[simlist]` even needed here?

Comment: @user366312, only for what I mentioned in my answer. You could return your simulation result as just `simlist`, in which case states would be names as `1:length(init)`. Now as to use the names provided by `labels`, we need instead `labels[simlist]`, which works as in the example in my answer. I.e., state 1 will now be renamed to `labels[1]`, state 2 to `labels[2]`, etc.